# Can't animate the exact object that I want in openGL & GLUT

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut

When I clicked the right button on the particular object it gets started to animate. However, whether I click on the same object to stop it -the animating one- or any other object which is not animating, the animating object stops. But, I want animating object to be stopped only when I click on it.

How can I fix this problem? Here is my onClick and onTimer functions. Should I use the animating bool in structure? if so, how?

```
if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {

        for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
            if(mx >= arr[i].xB + 0 && mx <= arr[i].xB + 130 && my <= arr[i].yB + 17 && my >= arr[i].yB + - 17){
                animation = !animation;
                animationNumber = i;
                printf("TRUE\n");
            }
        }

void onTimer( int v) {

    glutTimerFunc( TIMER_PERIOD, onTimer, 0) ;


    if(animation){
        arr[animationNumber].xB++;
    if(arr[animationNumber].xB >= 640)
        arr[animationNumber].xB -= 1410;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay() ; // display()

}
```

Comment: The title is wrong. The problem is in the description. I don't want the animating object to be stopped when I click another object.

Comment: How is this related to OpenGL?

Comment: I am drawing a rocket some other things by using OpenGL

Comment: Store `animationNumber` in an array. In `onClick` check, if `i` in an array. If it is - remove it, otherwise add it. In `onTimer` iterate thru the whole array.

Comment: still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array `bool animation[MAX]` instead of the single boolean variable `animation` and the indexing variable `animationNumber`.
With this solution each object has its own state which indicates if it is "animating" or stands still.

```cpp
bool animation[MAX] = {};
```

Change the corresponding state of the object in the array, when the mouse button is pressed:

```cpp
if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
{
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if (mx >= arr[i].xB + 0 && mx <= arr[i].xB + 130 &&
            my <= arr[i].yB + 17 && my >= arr[i].yB + - 17)
        {
            animation[i] = !animation[i];
            printf("TRUE\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Traverse all the objects in the timer function and update the positions of the objects:

```cpp
void onTimer( int v) 
{
    glutTimerFunc( TIMER_PERIOD, onTimer, 0) ;

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
       if(animation[i])
       {
           arr[i].xB++;
           if( arr[i].xB >= 640)
               arr[i].xB -= 1410;
       }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```